# How to list all the messages from producer in consumer from beginning in kafka (Windows)?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

[How to list all the messages from producer in consumer from beginning in kafka (Windows)?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCNXm.png)

Not able to display message from producer from beginning in kafka-windows

Answer (score 1):

Console **producer** does not read data. Use the consumer instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in windows powershell:

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic cities --from-beginning
```